# Idiomatic Scala way to filter void values from list

Tags: scala

I have code like:

```
val mylist = (1,2,3)
val filteredList: List[Int] = mylist.map { num =>
   if (num < 3) num
}
```

So I want filteredList to contain (1,2). However, after this the type of filteredList is List[Any], not List[Int]. How do I remove the void/null/?? values to make it a true list of ints? I tried adding an else null clause then filtering out null values from filteredList, but it didn't seem like good Scala style...

Comment: `mylist.filter(_ < 3)`

Comment: Shortest form would be `mylist.filter(3>)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `myList` is actually `List(1, 2, 3)` and not the tuple `(1, 2, 3)`

You should use `filter` and not `map`. You don't want to put a single `if` statement within `map` (or even if/else usually). In this case it returns `Unit`, as the `else` is [filled in with `Unit`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#conditional-expressions) by the compiler.

That is, the compiler turns your code into:

```
val filteredList: List[Int] = mylist.map { num =>
   if (num < 3) num else ()
}
```

Which means you actually have

```
List(1, 2, Unit) // List[Any]
```

Instead use:

```
myList.filter(_ < 3)
```

Or the long form:

```
myList.filter(num => num < 3)
```

---

(Related to comments) You can also use `collect` to both filter and map in one step using pattern matching.

```
myList.collect { case num if(num < 3) =>
   num // or do something with num to return a different type
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I was generalizing my problem and made a tuple not a list as I intended. Would this still be good practice if, in my example, if (num < 3) then I create a large object? I'd rather just not create the object then make them all and filter after.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Sorry. In my actual use case (this is a huge generalization) I want to initialize an instance of a class using the num as a parameter, but only if it's less than 3. So, mylist & filteredList should be of type List[MyObject]. So, if I move the filter statement to the end, I'm creating all the instances, then only using a small subset. I'd rather just not create all the instances in the first place.

Comment: I see, so then you can `filter` first, then `map` to `MyObject`. You could also do that in one step using `collect`, but that's a somewhat different question than the original.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you want to use `filter` instead of `map`:

```
val filteredList = mylist.filter(num => num < 3)
```

Or abbreviated:

```
val filteredList = myList.filter(_ < 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

`mylist` is a `Tuple3` and not a `List` as you mention. If `myList` is declared like this `val mylist = List(1,2,3)` then you can easily filter it and get back a `List[Int]` using `filter`

```
val mylist = List(1,2,3)

mylist.filter(num => num < 3)
res0: List[Int] = List(1,2)
```

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I was generalizing my problem and made a tuple not a list as I intended. Would this still be good practice if, in my example, if (num < 3) then I create a large object? I'd rather just not create the object then make them all and filter after.